# How can I use hist_ignore_dups to ignore duplicate lines in zsh with extended_history enabled?

Tags: zsh

When enabling `hist_ignore_dups` in `zsh`, I find there are many duplicate lines in `$HISTFILE`.

(Note: `HISTFILE="$HOME/.zsh_history"`)

```bsh
$ cat $HISTFILE

: 1593874281:0;ls
: 1593874287:0;l
: 1593874288:0;ls
: 1593874291:0;l
```

I think `hist_ignore_dups` should solve this. (`HIST_IGNORE_DUPS` http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html).

But duplicate lines still appeared in `$HISTFILE`, even though `hist_ignore_dups` is already enabled by `ohmyzsh` with [history](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/079e7bb5e0a79171f3356d55d3f6302a82645a39/lib/history.zsh#L34-L39) plugin.

```
## History command configuration
setopt extended_history       # record timestamp of command in HISTFILE
setopt hist_expire_dups_first # delete duplicates first when HISTFILE size exceeds HISTSIZE
setopt hist_ignore_dups       # ignore duplicated commands history list
setopt hist_ignore_space      # ignore commands that start with space
setopt hist_verify            # show command with history expansion to user before running it
setopt share_history          # share command history data
```

I suspect that `extended_history` and `hist_ignore_dups` are in conflict.

Answer (score 16):

As per [the documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-HISTIGNOREDUPS):

> `HIST_IGNORE_DUPS` (`-h`)
>
> Do not enter command lines into the history list if they are duplicates of the previous event.

Note that it's *"the"* previous event and **not** "any" previous event.

If you want to ignore *all* dups, you will need to set…

*drum roll*

You guessed it: `HIST_IGNORE_ALL_DUPS`

From [the documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-HISTIGNOREALLDUPS):

> `HIST_IGNORE_ALL_DUPS`
>
> If a new command line being added to the history list duplicates an older one, the older command is removed from the list (even if it is not the previous event).